# How do you replicate a virtualenv?

Tags: python, virtualenv

I just started using virtualenv in python.

I'm installing several package(?) using pip on the virtualenv.

Is there a record what packages are installed in a virtualenv so that I can replicate the same environment in a different machine?

Comment: `pip freeze`: http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/requirements.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On the first virtual env:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

On the second:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Easy!

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to make your virtualenv relocatable and then recursively copy it.

```
virtualenv --relocatable "$path_to_existing_virtual_env"
cp -r "$path_to_existing_virtual_env" "$path_to_duplicate_virtual_env"
```